# How to host CouchDB database?

Tags: couchdb

I have CouchDB database running on `http://localhost:5984/` but I want to host it on IIS to be accessed from other computer from the network. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The other computer may well be able to use it on port 5984 the way you already have things set up.

But if you want to expose it via IIS, what you're looking for is setting up IIS as a "reverse proxy" (that is, as a front-end to another server process, in this case the CouchDB server process). [This question and its answers on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server) may help.